# HPC BrokerClient takes a long time to execute and throws an error on trying to get results

Tags: c#, wcf, soa, hpc

I am trying to get my sample WCF service to run on a on-premise HPC 2012 SP1 cluster. It's an 2012 HPC WCF application. My test service is deployed to all Compute nodes in a

cluster and configuration file is deployed on a head node too. In my client application I am using BrokerClient wrapper over my service proxy client. By using HPC Cluster

Manager I can see that my service is invoked and ran, but it is very slow, it takes him about 5 minutes to finish executing (and it's a simple test service, without intensive

operations). And also in my client application I am getting he following error after tasks finished executing on a cluster:

"Broker is unavailable due to loss of heartbeat. 
Make sure you can connect to the broker node, the HpcBroker service is running on the broker node and the session is still running."

here is my client code:

```
    SessionStartInfo info = new SessionStartInfo(this.textBox1.Text, this.textBox2.Text);
        info.SessionResourceUnitType = SessionUnitType.Core;
        info.Secure = false;
        info.MinimumUnits = 1;
        info.MaximumUnits = 1;
        using (Session s = Session.CreateSession(info))
        {
            NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None, false);
            using (BrokerClient<IHpcTestService> client = new BrokerClient<IHpcTestService>(s, binding))
            {
                ApplyCalculationsRequest request = new ApplyCalculationsRequest("test");

                client.SendRequest<ApplyCalculationsRequest>(request);
                client.EndRequests();

                foreach (var resp in client.GetResponses<ApplyCalculationsResponse>())
                {
                    this.label3.Text = resp.Result.ApplyCalculationsResult;
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
```

P.S. when I try to use plain proxy client, without BrokerClient wrapper, everything works just fine.

Any ideas on the above?

Answer (score 0):

Regrading the slowness, you'd need to provide more specifics about what kind of slow down you are talking about.  You can see slowness in various areas and each one is caused by something different.

If it is slowness in Job Creation, this happens on the Head Node
If it is slowness in submission of tasks to job and executing EndRequests, this happens on the Broker node as the requests are written to the MSMQ folder on the broker node brokering the job.
If it is slowness in job runtime, then this is an issue with the worker nodes; this could be caused by a slow database connection, or general slowness in your application, or if you are using central shared location for the service instead of a local copy this could also cause slowness.

As for the error you are getting:

"Broker is unavailable due to loss of heartbeat. Make sure you can connect to the broker node, the HpcBroker service is running on the broker node and the session is still running."

When using the BrokerClient wrapper for whatever reason HPC sends 2 final callback messages instead of just the one.  For any given job the final task in the list (but not necessarily the last executed task in the list) has a bool that designates it as the last task.  When you have received all callbacks and you re-attach to the job and close it, it sends out a final message which you cannot open because the service channel was closed.  I do not know why it does this when you have a BrokerClient wrapper in place; I've yet to figure that out.  Essentially if I don't see that message more than once per job I ignore it at this point.

Out of curiosity can you post your code related to using a Proxy Client?